# How to get addition of diagonals in matrix using Swift?

Tags: ios, matrix

I want to get the addition of diagonals from Left to Right and Right to Left. And please share how do we have to solve the problems step by step. I have no idea about this. Please find the attachment.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried any code, so far?

Comment: No, I have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: Did you check stackoverflow if this was already answered?

Comment: yes. But i didn't get any exact answer what i require.

Comment: A good place to start is by looking for answers on how to make a matrix structure. There's a good chance that you'll come to an answer by yourself while doing that...

Comment: The above matrix structure is one of the interview task given to me. So that i think it is possible to resolve. But still i didn't get any idea about this. If anyone can faced this please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sumLeftToRight: Int = 0
var sumRightToLeft: Int = 0
var arr: [[Int]] = []

for i in 0..<arr.count {
   sumLeftToRight += arr[i][i]
   sumRightToLeft += arr[i][arr.count-i-1]
}
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you could show how to populate the array with data from the original post.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24182708/edit) your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Swift 5 Solution within a function with a bit different approach in case negative numbers in test-cases 
func sumDiagonally(arr:[[Int]])-> Int{
    var subn = 0
    var sum1st = 0
    var sum2nd = 0
    for i in 0..<arr.count{
        sum1st += arr[i][i]
        sum2nd += arr[i][arr.count-i-1]
        subn = sum1st - sum2nd
            if sum1st < sum2nd{
            subn = subn * -1
            }
        }
    return subn
}
sumDiagonally(arr: [[1,2,3],
                    [4,5,6],
                    [9,8,9]])
```

Comment: What's the idea of having "subn"? What's going on there? The code does not seem to produce correct outputs.